# What is the use of defining a mixin instead of a instance method in sequilizejs?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I was trying through some advanced techniques used to refactor `sequilize.js` models and came across how `instanceMethods` method can be used and util functions can be attached to it.

**Example**:

```
function get_instance_methods(sequelize) {
  return {
    is_admin : function() {
      return this.admin === true;
    },
  };
};
```

and then the above can be used like so :

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var instance_methods = get_instance_methods(sequelize);

  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
      email : {
          type      : DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull : false
      },
  }, {
      instanceMethods : instance_methods,
    });

    return User;
};
```

But now I came across a `mixin` being defined and then being used like so inside a modal **[HERE](https://github.com/timeoff-management/timeoff-management-application/blob/master/lib/model/db/user.js#L25)** .

```
 withCompanyAwareness.call ( instance_methods, sequelize ) ;
```

the code for the `mixin` itself is being defined [**HERE**](https://github.com/timeoff-management/timeoff-management-application/blob/master/lib/model/mixin/user/company_aware.js). A snapshot of what the mixin looks like can be found below :-

```
module.exports = function(sequelize){
  // more methods defined here .. just adding a snapshot here.
  this.get_company_with_all_leave_types = function() {
    return this.getCompany({
      include : [{
        model : sequelize.models.LeaveType,
        as    : 'leave_types',
      }],
      order : [
        [{ model : sequelize.models.LeaveType, as : 'leave_types' }, 'sort_order', 'DESC'],
        [{ model : sequelize.models.LeaveType, as : 'leave_types' }, 'name']
      ]
    });
  };

};
```

What exactly is the purpose of defining a mixin vs using instance methods? Why is there a need for defining a mixin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting question! Let's start with what is clear so far:

- the model should return the Model instance always
- to create the Model instance, in both cases `instanceMethods` is being set as an object which contains methods.

---

`get_instance_methods(sequelize)` returns an object of functions in both situations. In the first example, this object is not extended with new functions. The function which were returned, are passed to the Model creation, hence, what `get_instance_methods(...)` returns, that arrives in the model's `instanceMethods`.

If needed, we can modify the `instance_methods` object *before* we send it to the model:

```
instance_methods.myNewMethod = function () { ... }
```

This would add `myNewMethod` in the instance functions of the specific model where add this functionality, but not for the other models where we call the `get_instance_methods` for.

Now, let's assume that we have a third model that would need `myNewMethod` exaclty in the same way. In that case, we have two options: to duplicate the `myNewMethod` function in the second and third models, ending up with duplicated code which is not fun, or **create a mixin**!

What is a *mixin* in this case? Just a function to *unify* that eventual duplicate code.

Hence, we can have a mixin function called:

```
function with_my_new_method () {
    this.myNewMethod = function () { ... }
}
```

So, in the models we would have:

```
// Model1.js:
var instance_methods = get_instance_methods(sequelize);
var Model1 = sequelize.define("Model1", {
  ...
}, {
  instanceMethods: instance_methods
});

// Model2.js:
var instance_methods = get_instance_methods(sequelize);
with_my_new_method.call(instance_methods)
var Model2 = sequelize.define("Model2", {
  ...
}, {
  instanceMethods: instance_methods
});

// Model3.js:
var instance_methods = get_instance_methods(sequelize);
with_my_new_method.call(instance_methods)
var Model3 = sequelize.define("Model3", {
  ...
}, {
  instanceMethods: instance_methods
});
```

When calling the `with_my_new_method` mixin function with `.call`, that means we are passing the `instance_methods` as context to the function. So, `instance_methods` would become `this` inside of the mixin functions.

#### Conclusion

In this case the mixin functions work as utility functions to *extend* the instance methods object with new methods.

Comment: @Ionica thank you for taking the time for the long explanation , you've theoretically answered my question , i'll go try this out now by myself and see how it work. Thanks a ton :D